# QTKit creating threads that never die when I play new movies

Tags: movie, qtkit, reward

I have an app that composes movies and then plays them via QTMovieView.  Each time I [movieView setMovie:newMovie], QTKit creates a new thread that never dies.  It also appears that the movie is never dealloced. I created a simple example that illustrates the problem:

http://cl.ly/371e0p443Q2K0R3f0Q1w/MovieLeak.zip

I will happily pay someone to solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a big fat memory leak in this method:

```
-(void)restartMovie {
    QTMovie *m = [movieView movie];
    [m stop];
    [movieView setMovie:[m copy]]; // <- copy creates an object THAT YOU OWN!!!
    [movieView play:self];
}
```

so this behavior is expected.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that copy didn't autorelease